# Extended ASCII code above 255

Tags: ascii

I was always under the assumption ASCII codes ranged from 0 to 255. Last night I had to deal with a character that I thought was an underscore but turned out to be Chr(8230). Three little dots resembling an underscore. This was in an AutoHotKey script. Problem solved but it left me with questions.

I found a table with Chr(8230) and more.

http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/table-of-ascii-characters-and-symbols-for-coldfusion/

There's a vague reference to these codes and Coldfusion which just added to the Confusion.

Out of curiosity, what are the codes above 255 referred to as and are there more tables like this? I know they are not Extended ASCII (128 to 255) but can't find any reference to them other that the above chart.

A simple name will be enough. I'm a retired tech with limited programming and internet searching abilities and really don't care if a question like this is beneath some here. If it ruffles a few feathers then so be it, the voting system here is absolutely meaningless to me. :)

Comment: ASCII codepoints are numbered 0 to 127. "Extended ASCII" implies 0 to 255, with 0 to 127 being the same as ASCII, but otherwise isn't a very useful term because dozens of character sets are "extended ASCII."

Comment: That's not ASCII or Extended ASCII. That's a Unicode character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a unicode character.  A multi-byte character set that accommodates many characters from different languages that the standard ASCII character set could not reproduce. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm

Here is the Wikipedia entry on Unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Here's one of many Unicode tables available online: http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character

Comment: Unicode was the key. I would add a Thank You but I'm not supposed to so I won't.   :)

Comment: You're not implying that Unicode has an encoding with all codepoints fitting into two bytes, are you?  The only fixed-width encoding for Unicode is UTF-32, which is four bytes per codepoint.

Comment: @Lorence: You should accept the answer as it solved the issue. You can do so by clicking in the tick below the down vote button.

Comment: AFAIK: A Unicode sequence is comprised of the first 7 bits of the first byte indicate the number of following bytes..